# picture slider with controls

Tags: jquery, css

how to to make image slider .

**I want** that when I click on the image it should show

full image and also there should be controls to go forward or backward of images

Comment: You might want to take the [tour] and visit [ask] and then address your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps you out.

**jQuery**:

```
$("img").click(function(){ // when an image is clicked
    $(this).toggleClass("expand"); // toggle "expand" class
});
```

**CSS**:

```
img{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.0);
    transition: all 500ms;
}
img.expand{ // when an image has the class "expand"
    transform: scale(2.0); // double size of clicked image
}
```

Tell me if this helps you out or solved your vague question. :)

And please remember to actually try stuff yourself in the future, before coming here!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just using an existing library such as http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

It has all the functionality that you wanted, and is easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fancybox. Its one of the best solution for your problem. refer: http://fancybox.net/